# Previously Copied range values being over written by newly copied data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Previously Copied range values being over written by newly copied data
There are 4 pars to the function I am developing.

Part 1: copies a row of data starting from row “i” located in range “Ai:Pi” – where i = the row number, one at a time, to a different location – range “A5:P5” (I have called input data staging range) on the same sheet. WORKS FINE

Part 2: The data from the staging range is then pulled into another spreadsheet for processing. WORKS FINE

Part 3: The processed data from the other spreadsheet is then copied back into the original spreadsheet – range “T5-AA5” (which I have called processed data staging range). WORKS FINE

Part 4: I then want to copy the VALUES only from the range “T5:AA5”  to the same row “i” as the input data, so that the range to be copied is “Ti:AAi”. NOW WORKING.

I have tested what I am looking to do in Excel and it works perfectly well when I am using PASTE SPECIAL However in Google Apps the problem is that whilst the values are copied to the right row “i”, they get over written by the new range of data to be copied. 
I really want to resolve PART 4.

My code is:

function getRowReturnValue() {

```
// "Form Responses 1" is the sheet with the Forms Data.
// The "Simple loop testing" sheet was set up to test the development of teh Apps scripts.

// Spreadsheet Sources
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var processor = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fuGpv7YsyM5sCAMC25UkpfEURm06fJjyieezY3CjMl4/edit")// This is the PROCESSOR spreadsheet where 


// Data source sheets in the source spreadsheets
        // NOTE: IF YOU CHANGE THE SHEET NAME, THEN YOU NEED TO CHANGE TH SHEET NUMBER IN THE SQUARE BRACKETS BELOW FOR SOURCE and DESTINATION variables
        // [0} = sheet 1 = "Form Responses 1"; [1] = "Test Sheet"; [2] = "Simple loop testing"

var spr = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
var processorOutputData = processor.getSheetByName("MASTER OUTPUT"); 

var source_sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];           // This is the location sheet of the FORMS INPUT data. In this case the "[0]" indicates the position of the very first sheet in the source spreadsheet
var target_sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];           // This is the location sheet of the PROCESSED data from the processor. In this case the "[0]" indiates the position of the very first sheet in the 
                                                // source spreadsheet


// Identify the number of rows of Forms Input data to be processed.  
var lastDataRow = spr.getLastRow();             // NOTE: This rule is identifies the last low number, ignoring blank rows in between. The disadvantage is that it looks at the WHOLE row and not just 
                                                // the cells of the row into which the Forms Input data will occupy
    Logger.log(lastDataRow);                    // CHECK

var NumbOfResponses = spr.getLastRow();         // CHECK
    Logger.log(NumbOfResponses);                // CHECK

// Clear the content of the staging row
var clearStagingRow = spr.getRange(5,1,1,16);   
    clearStagingRow.clearContent();


    for (var i = 10; i<NumbOfResponses+1;i++) {
       // Extract the input data VALUES, row by row, to be processed from the source sheet and put it into the INPUT STAGING area - which holds one row of data at a time.
       var values = source_sheet.getRange(i,1,1,16); 

           values.copyValuesToRange(target_sheet, 1, 16, 5, 5);               // Once the data is in the INOUT STAGING area, it is imported to the "MASTER OUTPUT" sheet in the processor spreadsheet.
                                                                              // This data is then processed and the resulting output data is posted in a range ready to be copied back into 
                                                                              // the "Forms responses 1" sheet

       // Identify the source range from the "MASTER OUTPUT" processor sheet. Identify the target range in the PROCESSED STAGING range in the "Forms responses 1" sheet
       var processedData = processorOutputData.getRange("d43:k43").getValues();            // Identify the range in the "MASTER OUTPUT" from where the data is to be sourced
       var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("T5:AA5").setValues(processedData);                    // Identify the target range in the PROCESSED STAGING area where the input is to be put


       // Copy PROCESSED OUTPUT data from OUTPUT STAGING range to the row alligned to the input data
       var retValues = source_sheet.getRange(5,20,1,8);
           retValues.copyValuesToRange(target_sheet, 20, 27, i, i);

       // Clear out the data previously copied into the OUTPUT STAGING data
          target_range.clearContent();

 }
```

}

Comment: Have considered disabling the form while you run this function?

Comment: Why do you do this everytime within the loop.`var processedData = processorOutputData.getRange("d43:k43").getValues();           
    var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("T5:AA5").setValues(processedData);`

Comment: I am copying the processed data from another spreadsheet (range d43:k43) back to the source spreadsheet. The range in the source sheet where this data is received is "T5:AA5" (or as I have called it processed output staging range). The reason for repeating it in the loop is that there will be several rows of input data in the source spreadsheet that need to be processed one at a time

Comment: That seems like a convoluted way to go.  Why not just have a script run off of a time based trigger with a period of n minutes.  Then process the last n minutes of data and stop. You  can take the date out of the Form Response sheet and store the results in another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed and redesigned the model and fortunately the simplicity has resolved the issue. The code that works well is
           var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,1,1,16); // identify range and location where data is sourced
           var source_values = source_range.getValues();       // get thevalues in the location
           var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(8,4,1,16); // identify the range and location of where the data is to be copied in the processor
               target_range = target_range.setValues(source_values);  // copy the values in the target range and location in the processor

```
       var targetoutput_range = target_sheet.getRange(38,4,1,8); // identify range and location of where the processed data is
       var targetoutput_values = targetoutput_range.getValues(); // get the output values
       var destoutput_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,18,1,8);   // identify the range and location of where the output data will be copied
           destoutput_range = destoutput_range.setValues(targetoutput_values);  // copy the output values in the destination range and location
```

I run the above in a loop and that posts output values in the same row as input data.
The issue that I have is that as the number of inout rows gets large, the time taken for the data to be processed is increasing. 
My answer was to have the only the new rows evaluated and the 'older' rows left untouched. My code for this works but the time taken does not happen to be shortened.
So if there are suggestions on how I can shorten the time then please recommend.